# Best way to code number pad in iOS8 for Swift

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I'm looking to code a tip calculator using Swift and was wondering the best way to code the number pad for it?

The number pad will always be on the screen, and it would be cool if it lit up like the iOS8 Keypad when the buttons are pressed.

The below is an example from dribbble for reference.

[image]

Comment: The question is what's the best way to code the UIButtons? Is it just dragging 12 buttons onto the screen? Do I have to create an image for each one? If am creating an image, do I create them in retina and they automatically scale down?

Answer (score 2):

Those UI elements appear to `UIButton` items, which are very customizable. This would not be a difficult UI to replicate.

To get them to "light up," you could highlight them on tap down event.

Comment: Would the UIButtons be an image? If so, how would you emulate the way they "light up" like they do on iOS8? I believe there's a small fade in transition

Comment: Yeah, you can set a UIButton to have an image. And to highlight it, you could [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/imageForState:) to change the image when you tap it.

Comment: That's amazing. Do you know if there's also a way to add a tap effect like Google Material Designs? http://codepen.io/iraycd/pen/dHrxv